# How to make the table header align center in asp.net mvc?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is the code for my table in asp.net mvc.

```
<div class="span4 proj-div text-center" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addLanguageModal">
<u>Add Language</u>
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark-header table-responsive">
    <tr class="text-center">
        <th>Language Name</th>
        <th>Welcome Message</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>


    @foreach (var item in Model.Languages)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LanguageName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditLanguage", "Country", new { id = item.LanguageId })|
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLanguage", "Country", new { id = item.LanguageId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The screen likes:
[image]

You see the header is on the left. I want the header text is in the center.
Can we use bootstrap class to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to each `th` the classname `class="text-center"`.

Or in your CSS:

```
th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Bootstrap documentation - alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)